# Converting JavaScript to Groovy/Java

Tags: javascript, groovy, timezone, katalon-studio

I have some javascript code (Postman) that needs to be converted for use in another API test tool (Katalon). I am getting errors while updating the date with the timezone difference.

The error occurs when trying to update the expectedDate with the TZ difference.

Original Javascript

```
//Postman - Validate Date
/*var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var expectedDate = new Date();
var firstDate = new Date(jsonData[0].Date);
var locationOffset = Number(pm.environment.get("locationOffset"));
var tzDifference = locationOffset * 60 +       expectedDate.getTimezoneOffset();
expectedDate = new Date(expectedDate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 *  1000);
firstDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
pm.test("Testing Date - Expected: " + expectedDate + " & Returned: "  + firstDate, function (){
    pm.expect(firstDate.getDate()).to.be.eql(expectedDate.getDate());
});*/
```

Converted

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

//get expected date
Date expectedDate = new Date()
println('ExpDate: ' + expectedDate)

//get first date
String newDateAdded = parsedJson.DailyForecasts[0].Date
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM- dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
Date firstDate = dateFormat.parse(newDateAdded)
println("FirstDate: " + firstDate)

//get offset
def locationOffset = GlobalVariable.gmt_offset.toDouble() //gmt_offset = -4

//get TZ difference
def tzDifference = locationOffset * 60 +   expectedDate.getTimezoneOffset()
println("tzDifference: " + tzDifference)

//update exp date (error here: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException:  Could not find matching constructor for:  java.util.Date(java.lang.Double)
expectedDate = new Date(expectedDate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 *  1000)
println('ExpDate: ' + expectedDate)

//update first date
firstDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000)
```

Error: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Date(java.lang.Double)

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I don't see a semicolon at the end of that line.

Comment: Why is `locationOffset` a `double` and not a `long`? I'm not that proficient in Groovy but I assume the rules are similar to those in Java, i.e. `locationOffset` being a `double` results in the result of the calculation of the `new Date(...)` parameter being a `double` as well. If `locationOffset` needs to be a `double` then you should make sure `locationOffset * 60`, `tzDifference` or at least `tzDifference * 60 *  1000`  is a `long` in the end.

Comment: What json are you getting as an input, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: @tim_yates  json input is "Date":"2019-05-20T07:00:00-04:00"

Comment: Logs: https://ibb.co/r7gjf7Q

Comment: @Thomas if I change it to a long I get: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-4.0"

Comment: Well, you need to convert that at some point. You can read the value as a `double` if you need to but in the end you need a `long`. -4.0 might indicate values like -4.5 would be possible as well so keeping `locationOffset` as a `double` might be ok. The result of your calculations needs to be a `long` in the end so put the cast/conversion where it's most appropriate, e.g.  at `tzDifference * 60 * 1000` in order to reduce rounding errors as much as possible (due to precision errors simple casts/truncation might result in wrong results, e.g. 199999.9 would then be 100000 instead of 200000).

Comment: What is the type of `GlobalVariable.gmt_offset`?

Comment: @tim_yates string

Comment: Maybe explaining what the output you require is?  I think this is all much simpler using Java 8's `ZonedDateTime` classes, but I am not sure if my results are what you are expecting to get from either of the above examples

Comment: eg, you can do:  `ZonedDateTime firstDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(parsedJson.DailyForecasts[0].Date)` and then create another for `now` in the same timezone with `ZonedDateTime expectedDate = ZonedDateTime.now().withZoneSameInstant(firstDate.zone)`

Comment: @tim_yates you can see the final javascript output in this screenshot. That is what is compared in the end -  https://ibb.co/r7gjf7Q

Comment: @tim_yates I also need to account for the offset from UTC (-4,-7, etc.) in firstDate. When I do the compare they should have the same date. I am pulling in the offset based on the location (New York, LA, London). Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain in words what it's supposed to do? I'm just getting more confused

Comment: @tim_yates basically adjust the dates (expectedDate and firstDate) to account for the known timezone difference (locationOffset) to ensure that the dates are equal.

Comment: which dates are equal?  `expectedDate` and `firstDate`?

Comment: @tim_yates yes, expected and first

Comment: @tim_yates your ZonedDateTime suggestion worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To run JS code in Katalon Studio, you can use JavaScript [Executor](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-execute-javascript.html#description-):

```
String postman ='''
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var expectedDate = new Date();
var firstDate = new Date(jsonData[0].Date);
var locationOffset = Number(pm.environment.get("locationOffset"));
var tzDifference = locationOffset * 60 +       expectedDate.getTimezoneOffset();
expectedDate = new Date(expectedDate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 *  1000);
firstDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
pm.test("Testing Date - Expected: " + expectedDate + " & Returned: "  + firstDate, function (){
    pm.expect(firstDate.getDate()).to.be.eql(expectedDate.getDate());
});
'''
WebUI.executeJavaScript(postman, null)
```