# Can e2e test cases in Katalon be written in Javascript language

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, katalon-studio

As far as I understand, Katalon (https://www.katalon.com/ - a tool for e2e testing) can record your actions and make test case scripts out of them (which use Selenium).

You can also write your own test case scripts directly in a programming language.

I'm wondering if the language in which test case scripts are written is only Java, or any other language (Javascript in particular) can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test cases are actually written in Groovy. Only Groovy/Java are natively supported.

However, there is a workaround way of using JavaScript with `WebUI.executeJavaScript()` method. You can see an example of using JS code in Katalon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238677/converting-javascript-to-groovy-java/56269506#56269506).

Comment: Thanks. I saw that, this is more like a custom script execution. So not a way of writing test cases in JS (or to have manual step recordings to output steps in JS commands), but a workaround, right?